# How to add a word file content to a crystal report?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, ms-word, converters

I am working on a web application project in **visual studio Ultimate 2013**. 
In this project, I am using crystal report templates where I need to design a template for a long word file (15 pages long).

**My question is:**

(*Is there any possible way to add the word file contents with its format to the crystal report template directly without having to design it all from scratch ?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in the past by creating a text box on the report canvas. Copy and paste the contents of your Word Doc into the text box. Maybe 1 text box per Word Doc page as I am not sure if there is a text limit in a text box. Im sure there is. All formatting will come with it. Then you can drag database and formula fields into the text box where they would need to go in Word Doc. It gets a bit time consuming to put together but works for me.